# How to add new colums in AWS Databrew based on some logic and values in existing colums

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-databrew

I have a CSV which I'm seeing in my AWS Databrew.
I have a column which has CIDR column (cidr_value) having ip values like `1.0.0.0/24`, `1.0.1.0/24`, etc.

I want to create three new cols like

```
col1 = network_head (ie. js equivalent `cidr_value.split(".")[0]`)

col2 = lower int range of ip

col3 = upper int range of ip
```

And finally I want to save this data in a new CSV.

I know there is a web function known as **IP_TO_INT** to calculate the integer value of an ip, but it takess ip not cidr value